# Перемещение вверх по папкам Bat

Tags: cmd, bat

Такое дело: я могу получить путь, из которого был запущен Bat-файл (%~dp0).
Можно как-нибудь быстро и легко получить путь, например, на два уровня выше?

Пример:

От

```
D:\AutoBuilder\Project\Source\Build
```

До

```
D:\AutoBuilder\Project
```

Может что-нибудь типа:

```
..\..\$(%~dp0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Может что-нибудь типа: ....\$(%~dp0)

Почти. Попробуй:

```
%~dp0..\..\
```

Comment: Не работает. Выдаёт: D:\AutoBuilder\Project\Source\Build..\..\

Comment: Был не прав, просто он не изменяет этот параметр, поэтому не выводит новый путь в echo, а если перемещаться через команду cd - всё в порядке.